I'm using sklearn 1.4.1 but random forest still cannot handle missing values
I've read that random forest algorithm in sklearn > 1.4 should be able to handle NaN. I've checked that I've the latest version of Sklearn.
! pip install --upgrade scikit-learn

import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)

1.4.1

however i still get the error:
ValueError: Input X contains NaN.
RandomForestClassifier does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might want to consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively. Alternatively, it is possible to preprocess the data, for instance by using an imputer transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with missing values. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html You can find a list of all estimators that handle NaN values at the following page: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values

Why? Should I import something else? I'm confused.
edit:
this is a minimal code that should give the error I've mentioned:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# Example DataFrame with NaN values
data = {
    "tipo_locazione": ["A", "B", None, "A"],
    "flg_polizza_caa": [1, 0, 1, 0],
    "cl_bisogni_3": [0, 1, 1, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def random_forest_model(variabili):
    X = df[variabili]
    y = df['cl_bisogni_3'].astype(str)

    # Identifying categorical features
    categorical_features = X.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns

    # Transformer for categorical features
    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
    ])

    # Preprocessor to apply transformations
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)
        ],
        remainder='passthrough'
    )

    # Model pipeline
    model = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
    ])

    # Splitting the dataset
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    # Fitting the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("Model trained successfully")

# Attempt to train the model with NaN values
variables = ['tipo_locazione', 'flg_polizza_caa']
random_forest_model(variables)

edit2 my traceback error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-1a77bdc05207> in <cell line: 65>()
     66     selected_variables = sample(variabili_ab, 2)  # Adjust number to be <= length of variabili_ab
     67 
---> 68     metrics = random_forest_model(selected_variables)
     69     results[tuple(selected_variables)] = metrics
     70     count_cicli -= 1

8 frames
<ipython-input-75-1a77bdc05207> in random_forest_model(variabili)
     47 
     48     # Fitting the model
---> 49     model.fit(X_train, y_train)
     50     y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
     51 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1472                 )
   1473             ):
-> 1474                 return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1475 
   1476         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **params)
    473             if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":
    474                 last_step_params = routed_params[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 475                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **last_step_params["fit"])
    476 
    477         return self

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1472                 )
   1473             ):
-> 1474                 return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1475 
   1476         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    375         estimator = type(self.estimator)(criterion=self.criterion)
    376         missing_values_in_feature_mask = (
--> 377             estimator._compute_missing_values_in_feature_mask(
    378                 X, estimator_name=self.__class__.__name__
    379             )

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in _compute_missing_values_in_feature_mask(self, X, estimator_name)
    212 
    213         if not self._support_missing_values(X):
--> 214             assert_all_finite(X, **common_kwargs)
    215             return None
    216 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, estimator_name, input_name)
    214     Test failed: Array contains non-finite values.
    215     """
--> 216     _assert_all_finite(
    217         X.data if sp.issparse(X) else X,
    218         allow_nan=allow_nan,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype, estimator_name, input_name)
    124         return
    125 
--> 126     _assert_all_finite_element_wise(
    127         X,
    128         xp=xp,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite_element_wise(X, xp, allow_nan, msg_dtype, estimator_name, input_name)
    173                 "#estimators-that-handle-nan-values"
    174             )
--> 175         raise ValueError(msg_err)
    176 
    177 

ValueError: Input X contains NaN.
RandomForestClassifier does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might want to consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively. Alternatively, it is possible to preprocess the data, for instance by using an imputer transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with missing values. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html You can find a list of all estimators that handle NaN values at the following page: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values


print(pd.__version__)
print(np.__version__)

2.0.3
1.25.2


1.4.1 sorry that's it

What is the actual code that's throwing the error? What criterion did you use for the RandomForestClassifier?

The cose is a bit long. I was using Gini criterion as specified in the documentations. I'll try to add a semplified version of my code

Thanks. An [mcve] is always good to have.

added a minimal version of the code

I don't get an error. Could you 1/ add the actual traceback for this code sample, and 2/ add your NumPy and Pandas version?

Added now in edit2

It looks like the traceback is not from the code in the question. The line metrics = random_forest_model(selected_variables) (and following lines) is not in the code sample. Please provide the traceback of your code sample, not of the actual code, for reproducibility.

I have sklearn.__version__, pd.__version__, np.__version__ yielding '1.4.1.post1', '2.0.3', '1.25.2'. Your example code sample in the question does still not raise an exception. Please restart the kernel of your notebook and try again.

There is a fillna method for pandas dataframes. For example:
df["tipo_locazione"].fillna(-1)

Then use the model as usual
